# Polarisation states in 1d?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, radiation, thermal-radiation

I am working through a derivation of the spectral energy density in a 1d cavity. The derivation says that the number of modes (per unit volume) in a frequency interval $dv$ is given by: 
$$g(\nu)d\nu =\frac{2(\nu + d \nu -\nu) }{L\delta\nu }$$
where the $2$ is due to the two different polarisations of the light. But how can there be two different polarisations in only one dimension please can someone explain what we mean when we say we have $2$ polarisations?

Comment: The cavity is 1D, inside a 4D spacetime. You don't have any electromagnetism if your spacetime is two- or one-dimensional.

Comment: @ACuriousMind ok so the two polarisation states are two orthonormal polarisations (i.e. one vertically and one horizontally) that can be superimposed to from any such vacillation with that wavelength?

Comment: One can make a long waveguide that acts like a one dimensional or two dimensional cavity below a cutoff scale, so the answer to the question is really "it depends". If the cross section of the waveguide is square, one can have two polarizations, if it is squashed, then there will be only one that is effectively possible, the second polarization will be greatly suppressed... or so I think naively.